# System Clean Master kills my foreground service

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

I'm running a service that's in the foreground and has a constant notification.

One of my users told me that my app is killed by Clean Master (it's integrated into his android system, it's not a user app). If this app frees RAM it kills my service and it won't restart even though it is using `START_STICKY` and is using `startForeground` to run in foreground with a constant notification.

*I think this only is possible for a system app, because as far as I know, a foreground service can't be killed by a user app.*

Is there anything I can do about this? I want that my service restarts itself if it is killed, just like it's doing it in any other case...

My service looks like following:

```
public class OverlayService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        // prepare notification...
        // ...

        // start foreground
        super.startForeground(id, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Is there anything I can do about this?* yeah, ask user to add your app to "white list" if such exists in "Clean Master" or ask him to disable "Clean Master"(as they are bad by defualt)

Comment: He can't disable it, it's a system app and he's not rooted. I don't know why, but he says my app does not show up in the list of apps he could add to the whitelist...

Comment: you could try to detect if that package is installed and warn the user in your app, so to say "it's not my fault"

Comment: So far, my tests show, that my service is never stopped if clean master is a user app. It seems like the app misuses it's system app permissions if possible to clean ram more radically if possible... So the app itself is not a problem at all in most cases...